# Need to add an extra section to menu bar but code doesn't change it

Tags: css, navigation, menubar

I need to add a "jobs" page to the menu bar at the top of my website's homepage (and the other pages)

When i try to add one just by repeating the code that creates the current menu bar it adds it so that it's below the "home" tab. I need it at the side of the "contact us" link of each page.

I have looked at the css page but i didn't create it and can't figure out how to get it to display as i want it.

Please help me

```
/*menu*/
.menu { padding:10px 0 0 0; margin:0 ; width:410px;  float:left; }
.menu ul {  padding:0; margin:0; list-style:none; border:0; float:right;}
.menu ul li { float:left; margin:0; padding:0 5px; border:0;}
.menu ul li a { float:left; margin:6; padding:9px 0; color:#fff; font:normal 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration:none;}
.menu ul li a span { padding:10px 15px; background:none;}
.menu ul li a:hover {  background: url(images/menutest.gif) no-repeat right;}
.menu ul li a:hover span {   background:url(images/menutest.gif) no-repeat left;}
.menu ul li a.active {  background:url(images/menutest.gif) no-repeat right;}
.menu ul li a.active span {  background:url(images/menutest.gif) no-repeat left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the width of .menu may work for you because you have set the width of the .menu. if you don't want to change the width, probably you can reduce the padding of spans inside the Li of .menu ul.